# How to determine window size for modeling user behavior

Tags: data-mining, time-series

I am working in mining time series data for modeling user behavior. I collected the data from 37 smartphone users during 42 days(6 weeks). I want to use data during 3 weeks as model and the remaining as test (test performance of my model). The visualization of our data is following below:
[image]

In here, I want to ask what is the good `window size` for modeling user behavior, is one hour, one day, one week etc? or may be is there any good methods for determining window size?

Comment: Compare performance with different window sizes using cross validation.